# SELECT rows where seconds since epoch from NOW

Tags: sql, pdo

I am wondering is there a way to select only rows where time since epoch and "now()" is greater than a certain amount of seconds.

I store the rows with a field holding seconds since epoch created from the php function `time()`.

So something like this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE (now - field_time) > 60 seconds`

Comment: Is there something wrong with that code?

Comment: no but i don't know if SQL has a `now` function which has seconds since epoch ?

Comment: use `unix_timestamp` instead of `now`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NOW()` returns a SQL DateTime and what you need is `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` which returns seconds since epoch (unix timestamp) for now if you don't give any date as parameter.

Comment: depends on what _epoch_ you use, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Computing lists many epochs, but the most common is unix time I think.